# Excel Power Query loop for list of API's (coingecko.com)

Tags: excel, vba, data-science, powerquery

I have like a list of coin id's available from Coingecko.com in sheet1 and want the output of the api address (https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart/range?vs_currency=eur&from=1392577232&to=1422577232) in a sheet 2.

But as I have a lot of coin id's in the sheet1 and the list will change after time, I would like to have like a loop in the power query settings to output the coins prices in sheet2 automatically.

Until now I need to configure each api address through changing the /bitcoin/ term in the api address and then going through the settings in power query for each coin.

Does anyone know an approach?

[image: sheet1]
[image: sheet2]

I tried to manipulate the code by myself but as I am not really familiar with Power Query M, there is always an error. I also tried to create the sheet1 as a list in power query, but not 100% confident with it neither.

Answer (score 0):

You might manipulate the Queries.Formula. I have done the same exercise where I manipulate each Query by transferring 'Order' to my sub that forward this to manipulate each Formula. The function returns the new formula - and then the sub call for refresh of that query. You need to do some changes to this code:

```
Sub EditAllWorkbookFormuals(Order As String)
For Each q In ThisWorkbook.Queries
 q.Formula = NewQuery(q.Formula, Order)
 'q.Refresh
 ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - " & q.Name).Refresh
Next
End Sub

Function NewQuery(MyQuery As String, Order As String) As String
' This function replace a string parts of my web query API that return info of JSON order report.
' MsgBox MyQuery
' Use Select case, If, Inst, replace, and so on.
' .....
Pos1 = InStr(1, MyQuery, "GetOrderReport?order=") ' Find Start position to be replaced
If Pos1 > 0 Then Pos2 = InStr(Pos1, MyQuery, ")") ' Finds then End posistion to be replaced
If Pos1 > 0 Then
    
    ToBeReplaced = Mid(MyQuery, Pos1, Pos2 - Pos1 + 1)
    'MsgBox ToBeReplaced
    
    NewFilter = "GetOrderReport?order=" & Order & """)"
    'MsgBox NewFilter
    
    ' Replace the filter
    MyQuery = Replace(MyQuery, ToBeReplaced, NewFilter)
End If
' Parse the new string back to Sub as the NewQuery string to Formula
NewQuery = MyQuery
End Function
```